# Find out the next test method to execute in MS TestInitialize

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I keep the test data for specific test method in folder named the same as function. I previously had the same function call in each `[TestMethod]`, `ClearAllAndLoadTestMethodData()` which determined the method name via `StackTrace`. Now, I moved this function to `[TestInitialize]`. How can I find the name of the method that is about to be executed?

I thought `TestContext` provide this. I have access to it via `[AssemblyInitialize()]` and on first run its property `Name` is set to name of the testmethod. However, later this doesn't change (if I save the object in static field).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [AssemblyInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx) method is executed only once before all your tests.

Use the `TestContext` inside the `TestInitialize` method:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestIntialize()
    {
        string testMethodName = TestContext.TestName;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
    }

    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I didn't know I have to declare property.

Comment: I was looking for this feature and stumbled upon this great answer. Thanks.

Comment: TestContext  is a static property I can see, at least in the 2023 version

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    private static TestContext _testContext;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void TestFixtureSetup(TestContext context)
    {
        _testContext = context;
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestIntialize()
    {
        string testMethodName = MyTestClass._testContext.TestName;
        switch (testMethodName)
        {
            case "TestMethodA":

                //todo..

                break;
            case "TestMethodB":

                //todo..

                break;              
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodA()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodB()
    {
    }   
}
```