# C#: Override inherited method, but not for the whole class

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm just playing around a bit with inheritance and/or polymorphism in C#, and since my OOP skills are very, very basic I'm wondering if this is possible:

I have a class which inherits a method from a base class:

```
class BaseClass {
    public void Init () {
        // Do basic stuff.
    }
}

class LoginTest : BaseClass {
    public void StraightMethod () {
        // Do stuff based on the actions in the inherited Init() method from BaseClass.
    }

    public void ExceptionMethod () {
        // Do stuff where I don't want to do the actions in the inherited method.
        // That is, skip or override the Init() method in the BaseClass class.
    }
}
```

I know I can override the `Init()` method for the whole class, but is it possible to override it, or the code in it, for just the `ExceptionMethod()` method? These methods are run exclusively, so that for example one initialization of the `LoginTest` class will only run `LoginClass.ExceptionMethod()`, while another one might run `LoginClass.StraightMethod()`.

And yes, I know that good design will eliminate the need for things like this. But first of all, I'm not doing software engineering here, so being pragmatic is often OK without ruining some design or other principles. Second, this is more a question of whether or not something can be done, rather than the wiseness of it.

Note that these classes and methods are UnitTest methods, so the Init() method is a [TestInitialize] method. Hence, it's called automatically when LoginTest inherits from the BaseClass.

Comment: You can only override an abstract or virtual method, What do you mean by overriding inside a method ?

Comment: I think you are confusing things. `Init` is just a method, you don't 'override it' for just one other method. At what point are you calling `Init` anyway? If you need it called sometimes, but not others, then you should explicitly call it when needed and otherwise call a different method. This doesn't really have much to do with polymorphism.

Comment: That's logically impossible; you call `Init()` before you know which function will be called.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194289/find-out-the-next-test-method-to-execute-in-ms-testinitialize can help you. It describes how to get(at least I hope so) next test method that will be executed through TestContext. In any case you can just create one base class with all common test initialization and make two test classes for normal and specific cases.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't selectively override the `Init` method, but by making the `Init` method virtual, you can specify which version of the method you want to call with the `base` and `this` keywords:

```
class BaseClass
{
    // This method must become virtual
    public virtual void Init()
    {
        // Do basic stuff.
    }
}

class LoginTest : BaseClass
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        // Other stuff
    }

    public void StraightMethod()
    {
        // Do stuff based on the actions in the inherited Init() method from BaseClass.
        base.Init();
    }

    public void ExceptionMethod()
    {
        // Do stuff where I don't want to do the actions in the inherited method.
        // That is, skip or override the Init() method in the BaseClass class.
        this.Init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method isn't virtual, so it's not possible to override it at all, ever.

Answer (score 0):

You can't conditionally override the method, but you can call each one individually (if you provide the base functionality in the base class).

```
class BaseClass {
    public virtual void Init () {
        // Do basic stuff.
    }

}

class LoginTest : Baseclass {

    public override void Init() {
        //do overridden stuff
    }
    public void StraightMehthod () {
        this.Init(); // Call the overridden
    }

    public void ExceptionMethod () {
        base.Init(); // Call the base specifically
    }
}
```

As you have said though, this is probably not something you want to do as someone using this code will be very confused by the behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You also have the option to do this.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public void Init()
    {
        // Do basic stuff.
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass.Init");
    }
}

class LoginTest : BaseClass
{
    public void StraightMehthod()
    {
        // Do stuff based on the actions in the inherited Init() method from BaseClass.
        base.Init();
    }

    public void ExceptionMethod()
    {
        // Do stuff where I don't want to do the actions in the inherited method.
        this.Init();
        // That is, skip or override the Init() method in the BaseClass class.
    }

    private new void Init()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LoginTest.Init");
    }
}
```

Comment: At this point you may as well just give the method a different name.  It'd be functionally identical and noticeably clearer.

Comment: I just wanted to make everyone aware of the new keyword, since no one commented about it and many people said it can't be done.

Comment: That's because this isn't overriding the method.  The whole *point* of the `new` keyword is to call out the fact that it is very explicitly *not* being done.  All of the people that said you can't override the method if it's not `virtual` *were correct* and this in no way contradicts that statement.  You are creating a *new* method, not overriding an existing method, that new method just happens to share a name with an existing method.